# Cassandra update with Lightweight Transactions

Tags: cassandra

I want to implement the lightweight transaction for update  statement with SpringBoot Cassandra.
Ex:

```
UPDATE cyclist_id SET id = 15a116fc-b833-4da6-ab9a-4a3775750239 where lastname = 'WELTEN' and firstname = 'Bram' IF age = 18;
```

Is there any API available with CassandraTemplate  to achieve the above?
I tried using
`UpdateOptions updateOptions = UpdateOptions.builder().consistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM).build();` But not sure how to set the If condition with value (like age = 18)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution to implement lightweight transaction through SpringBoot Caasandra.

1. Create CqlSession using com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession builder.
2. Use PreparedStatement  - for query. In query use IF condition. and set the parameter to the query using BoundStatement.